# Is there a method of accessing an sql database from node that doesn't involve a server or php?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a project and need to access an SQL database from a node server but would prefer not to use a server or use php. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: "*not to use a server*" - you already have a server running the nodejs application, this doesn't make sense. "*or use php*" - yes, you absolutely don't php to run or connect to an sql database.

Comment: Sorry, more specifically I don't want to use an SQL server.

Comment: There are other SQL databases than the *Microsoft SQL server* one. They're all servers (for multiple clients to use) though, and there's nothing wrong with that. Or do you mean "server machine"? It can run on the same machine as your nodejs http server application.

Comment: Oh, you might be looking for an embedded database such as SQLite though

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways. Personally I like the combination of [knex.js](http://knexjs.org/) and [Objection.js](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/). but there are others like [Sequelize.js](https://sequelize.org/)